# Trouble emptying Queue

Tags: python, multiprocessing, queue, python-multiprocessing

### Question

I'm new to multiprocessing and for everything that I try I am getting nowhere. Every time that I think I figure something out I'm running into a new roadblock. My goal is to use multiple processes to load up a queue and then use multiple processes to pull from the queue and process data. I've tried reverting back to just basic queue processing but I can't get anything out of the queue once I implement multiple processes. What am I missing?

#### Code

```py
rom multiprocessing import Process, Lock
from queue import Queue
import os

q = Queue(5)


def get_from_q():
    print('trying to get')
    print(q.get())


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # put items at the end of the queue
    for x in range(6):
        print('adding ', x)
        q.put(x)

    PROCESSOR_COUNT = os.cpu_count()
    processes = []
    for p in range(PROCESSOR_COUNT):
        print('spawning process')
        p = Process(target=get_from_q)
        processes.append(p)

    for p in processes:
        print('starting')
        p.start()

    for p in processes:
        print('joining')
        p.join()
```

#### Result:

```
    adding 0
    adding 1
    adding 2
    adding 3
    adding 4
    adding 5
```

#### Expected Result

```
    adding 0
    adding 1
    adding 2
    adding 3
    adding 4
    adding 5
    spawning process
    spawning process
    spawning process
    spawning processv
    starting
    starting
    starting
    starting
    trying to get 
    0
    trying to get 
    1 
    trying to get 
    2 
    trying to get 
    3 
    trying to get 
    4
    trying to get 
    5
    joining
    joining
    joining
    joining
```

Comment: Have you tried swapping queue.Queue for multiprocessing.Queue?

Comment: Yeah, I started with that and then moved to this because it wasn't adding anything to the queue when I had mp.Queue

Comment: Your queue, which should be a `multiprocessing.Queue`, can only hold 5 records. Yet the very first thing you do is attempt to write 6 records. You will block on the 6th write. Then you are creating `cpu_count()` processes to read. If the number of processors you have are greater than 6, the extra processes you created will wait forever trying to read from an empty queue. You should explicitly set the pool size for us mere mortals trying to help you. You may know the number of processors that you have, but we don't.

Comment: @Booboo could I kill the extra processes with something like `if q.full(): break`

Comment: @Branden-Pincince Look at the documentation for `full()`. It says: **Return `True` if the queue is full, `False` otherwise. Because of multithreading/multiprocessing semantics, this is not reliable.** Do you want *reliable* code or do you want to just fool around? What if `q.full()` were reliable? So you would end up writing only 5 records. But what about the 6th record? You don't care if it never got written? Ask yourself, "What am I trying to accomplish?" I really cannot tell.

Comment: Based on what you said was your expected result and assuming you expected your program to terminate, I must deduce that `cpu_count()` must return 6 so that you would be creating exactly 6 processes, one process to read one record from the queue each. But now that there are only 5 records on the queue, one process will be hanging forever and your program will never terminate.

Comment: @Booboo I have a genetic algorithm and I thought I could use the queue to hold each member of the population. then pull from the queue and run a fitness function so that I can process the fitness score for each member of the population concurrently.

Comment: See my answer. Ultimately you should look at either class `Pool` from module `multiprocessing` or `ProcessPollExecutor` form module `concurrent.futures`.

Comment: @Branden-Pincince any feedback?

Comment: @ArtiomKozyrev I was able to get it to work using mp.Queue, although it's been a while since I figured it out. Unfortunately I only just now saw your comment. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running under a platform that uses `spawn` to create new processes, then when a new process is created, instead of inheriting a the address space of the main process, the new address space is instead initialized by re-executing all the code from the top of the program. That means whatever you have defined at global scope gets re-executed, for example in your code:

```py
q = Queue(5)
```

The implication is that this code is being executed by *every* process you are creating, which means that every process has its *own* copy of `q`. This cannot work. You need to create `q` once and pass it as an argument. I have also added *flush=True* to the `print` functions to reduce the chance that output from the various processes will be interleaved.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock, Queue
import os


def get_from_q(q):
    print('trying to get', q.get(), flush=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    PROCESSOR_COUNT = os.cpu_count()

    q = Queue(PROCESSOR_COUNT) # or put no size limitation on this

    # put items at the end of the queue
    for x in range(PROCESSOR_COUNT):
        print('adding ', x)
        q.put(x)

    processes = []
    for p in range(PROCESSOR_COUNT):
        print('spawning process')
        p = Process(target=get_from_q, args=(q,))
        processes.append(p)

    for p in processes:
        print('starting', flush=True)
        p.start()

    for p in processes:
        print('joining', flush=True)
        p.join()
```

Prints:

```
adding  0
adding  1
adding  2
adding  3
adding  4
adding  5
adding  6
adding  7
spawning process
spawning process
spawning process
spawning process
spawning process
spawning process
spawning process
spawning process
starting
starting
starting
starting
starting
starting
starting
starting
joining
trying to get 0
trying to get 1
trying to get 2
trying to get 3
trying to get 4
trying to get 5
trying to get 6
joining
joining
joining
trying to get 7
joining
joining
joining
joining
```

**Using a Process Pool**

Here the queue is hidden by the pool implementation:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count


def worker(x):
    print('x =', x, flush=True)
    return x ** 2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    PROCESSOR_COUNT = cpu_count()

    pool = Pool(PROCESSOR_COUNT) #
    print(pool.map(worker, range(PROCESSOR_COUNT)))
```

Prints:

```
x = 0
x = 1
x = 2
x = 3
x = 4
x = 5
x = 6
x = 7
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49]
```